# Load firestore data before google bots watch the content?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I load the firebase data before Google sees the content?

For example, retrieve data and render it with h1, p and other html tags, but my problem is SEO. I've been watching Gatsby JS but I don't need something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Firebase, the SEO is called **App Analytics** and it's possible to disable it on your database. However, you can only disable it generally and not load the data before it starts, once it's activated, it's always working, unfortunately.

I would recommend you to raise a Feature Request for this to be implemented [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list), so Google can check for further development.

Besides that, in case you want more information about how this is possible, you can check the below documentation.

- [Disable Analytics data collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection#disable_data_collection)

In addition, this question from the Community - [How to use Cloud Functions for Firebase to prerender pages for SEO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301989/how-to-use-cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-prerender-pages-for-seo) - there is a case that I believe might help you, since it's about pre-rendering content. This is for another type of use case, but I believe it might help.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thak you, I have applied the rendering of the page using the function and at the moment it does it well.