# Approach to rewrite React-Redux app to NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux

I want to rewrite my React-Redux App to Next JS for being it in Search WebSites. But I have no idea how to handle it, all actions with backend happened inside component lifecycles useEffect.

I want to understand first render in NextJs should happen in getInitialProps or getServerSideProps, so I dont need to use ComponendDidMount. Please anyboby help me understand the concept how to start it. In internet I can only see guides for begginers, but not for production projects.

Any help appreciated

Below you can see code of Main component, the question is how to rewrite in to NextJS to handle SEO

`
const MainPage = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

```
const refBannerControl = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

const [isCategorySelected, setIsCategorySelected] = useState(false);

const {
    skills,
    searchSkillValue,
    selectedFilters,
    vacancySearch,
    loadingVacancy,
    loadingSkills,
    jobCards,
    currentPage,
} = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.jobs);

const getSkills = () => {
    if (searchSkillValue.length > 0) {
        debounced();
    }
};

const vacancyBlockRef = useRef(null);

const onFocusFinder = () => {
    getSkills();

    const isMobile: boolean = window.innerWidth < 700;

    if (refBannerControl.current && isMobile) {
        refBannerControl.current.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    }
}

const debounced = useCallback(
    debounce(() => {
        dispatch(jobEffect.getSkills());
    }, 300),
    []
);

useEffect(() => {
    getSkills();
}, [searchSkillValue]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedFilters.length > 0) {
        dispatch(jobActions.setVacancyLoading(true));
        const lastSelected = selectedFilters[selectedFilters.length - 1];
        dispatch(jobEffect.getVacanciesBySkill(lastSelected.value));
    }
}, [selectedFilters]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (jobCards.length === 0 && !isCategorySelected && !loadingVacancy) {
        dispatch(jobEffect.getJobs());
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    ym('reachGoal', 'mainPageVisit');
}, []);

const handleLoadMoreJobs = () => {
    if (!loadingVacancy) {
        if (isCategorySelected) {
            dispatch(jobActions.setVacancyLoading(true));
            dispatch(jobEffect.getJobsByCategory(currentPage + 1));
        } else {
            dispatch(jobActions.setVacancyLoading(true));
            dispatch(jobEffect.getJobs(currentPage + 1));
        }
    }
};

const documentClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    dispatch(jobActions.setSkills([]));
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (skills.length > 0) {
        document.addEventListener('click', documentClick);
    } else {
        document.removeEventListener('click', documentClick);
    }

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', documentClick);
    };
}, [skills]);

// const expandCard = (id: string) => {
//     // dispatch(jobEffect.getDetailJobInfo(id));
// };

const onSelectCategory = (key: string) => {
    if (key === 'all') {
        setIsCategorySelected(false);
        dispatch(jobEffect.getJobs(currentPage, true));
    } else {
        setIsCategorySelected(true);
        dispatch(jobActions.setVacancyLoading(true));
        dispatch(jobEffect.getJobsByCategory(currentPage + 1, key));
    }
}

const dateNow = moment();
const startToday = moment().subtract(1, 'days')
const startWeek = moment().subtract(7, 'days')
const startMonth = moment().subtract(30, 'days')

let day = null;
let month = null;
let week = null;
let other = null;

const jobListDay = jobCards.map((item, index) => {
    if (moment(item.createdAt) < dateNow && moment(item.createdAt) >= startToday) {
        day = true;
        return (
            <React.Fragment key={item._id}>
                <JobCard
                    job={item}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
});

const jobListWeek = jobCards.map((item, index) => {
    if (moment(item.createdAt) < startToday && moment(item.createdAt) >= startWeek) {
        week = true
        return (
            <React.Fragment key={item._id}>
                <JobCard
                    job={item}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
});

const jobListMonth = jobCards.map((item, index) => {
    if (moment(item.createdAt) < startWeek && moment(item.createdAt) >= startMonth) {
        month = true
        return (
            <React.Fragment key={item._id}>
                <JobCard
                    job={item}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
});

const jobListOther = jobCards.map((item, index) => {
    if (moment(item.createdAt) < startMonth) {
        other = true
        return (
            <React.Fragment key={item._id}>
                <JobCard
                    job={item}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
});

return (
    <div className="main">
        <div className="container">
            <section className="banner">
                <div className="banner-control" ref={refBannerControl}>
                    <div className="banner-info">
                        <h1 className="banner-info__title">IWORKREMOTELY</h1>
                        <h2 className="banner-info__sub-title">ДОСТОЙНЫМ ЛЮДЯМ - ДОСТОЙНАЯ РАБОТА</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
                        <Finder
                            loading={loadingSkills}
                            value={searchSkillValue}
                            onChange={(value) => dispatch(jobActions.setSearchValue(value))}
                            onFocus={onFocusFinder}
                        />
                        <FinderAutocomplete
                            items={skills}
                            onSelect={(skill) => dispatch(jobActions.selectSkill(skill))}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section className="section">
                <CategoryList onSelect={onSelectCategory}/>
            </section>

            {selectedFilters.length > 0 &&
            <SelectedSkills
                items={selectedFilters}
                onDelete={(id) => dispatch(jobActions.deleteSelectSkill({id}))}
            />
            }

            {/*<VacancyTopBanner/>*/}

            <section className="section vacancy" ref={vacancyBlockRef}>
                {day && <div className="vacancy__dateBlock">Сегодня</div>}
                {jobListDay}
                {week && <div className="vacancy__dateBlock">На этой неделе</div>}
                {jobListWeek}
                {month && <div className="vacancy__dateBlock">В этом месяце</div>}
                {jobListMonth}
                {other && <div className="vacancy__dateBlock">В этом году</div>}
                {jobListOther}

                {loadingVacancy && <Spinner/>}

                <div className="loadMore">
                    <button className="btn btn_accent loadMore__button" onClick={handleLoadMoreJobs}>
                        Загрузить еще
                    </button>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>

        <div>
            <EmailSubscribe/>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

};

export default MainPage;
`

Answer (score 0):

In order for seo to work on react, you need to connect prerender services, react, of course, is not good friends with seo, but this is being treated

[How to use Cloud Functions for Firebase to prerender pages for SEO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301989/how-to-use-cloud-functions-for-firebase-to-prerender-pages-for-seo)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).